# why css3 calc doesn't work for height of div

Tags: css

I'm trying to use `calc()` to set my content's height to 100% - 50px, however it doesn't work as expected.

here is my [fiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/2dd0crzf)

I cannot figure out why, can anyone please help?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2dd0crzf/

Comment: How do you expect it to work? What's not working about it?

Comment: right now, the content <div> height looks always 100%, it will be covered by the <footer> under it. that's not I want. You could resize the browser to to see.

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/rqeLk5w0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the body margin, just zero it out and you should get the desired layout:

```css
body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
html{
  height:100%;
}
#content{
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
    height:calc(100% - 50px);
    background:blue;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    height:50px;
    
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">fsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    afsdfsa
    fsadf
    as
    fas
    df
    asdf
    saf
    <p>this is not last line</p>
    <p>last line</p>
</div>

<footer>
    i am footer
</footer>
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation(need at least 15) to upvote yet, but you answer resolved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you also have to add 100% height to your html:

```
html {height:100%;}
```

Comment: tired, still didn't get a <div> with height = 100% - 50px. I'm still seeing the footer is on top of the <div>